# Middleman 4.0.0 with HAML template engine gives error when starting with server command

Tags: haml, middleman

When executing 'middleman server' I get the following errors:

Haml::TempleEngine: Option :context is invalid
Haml::TempleEngine: Option :outvar is invalid

I tried updating middleman amongs other things.
This is my current gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "middleman", ">= 4.0.0"
gem "middleman-compass", ">= 4.0.0"
gem "jquery-middleman"
gem "middleman-sprockets", ">= 4.0.0.rc.1"
gem "rubocop"
gem "rubocop-junit-formatter"
gem "middleman-s3_sync"
gem "middleman-dotenv"
```

Haven't worked with middleman before so I would love some constructive advice.

Comment: Try starting with 'fresh' middleman install and see if you can run ``middleman server``, or better yet ``bundle exec middleman server`` without errors. If you can, try adding  gems one by one, saving Gemfile and restarting middleman server each time to see when you get this error. Also, I am not Ruby expert, but in my automatically-generated Gemfile, syntax is a bit different; for example: gem 'middleman', '~> 4.2', not gem "middleman", ">= 4.2"; not sure if this matters, but it is worth a try in lack of better answer.

Answer (score 7):

Today I had exactly this issue. Upon investigation I found that the warning originates from the `temple` gem, a templating engine used by Haml.

Of course this does not *solve* the problem (is it a problem, really?), but you can disable the warnings by putting this into `config.rb`:

```
# Disable warnings
Haml::TempleEngine.disable_option_validator!
```

Depending on where you put this line of code, you might need to `require 'haml'` before.

HTH!

Comment: How do we set this option for Sinatra apps?

Comment: You can just set it inside your Sinatra::Base Server.  Comments don't allow code formatting so I put it in a pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/nQptAW9G).